# Sql CretedDate Trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

This is the query I used for creating a trigger to update the `CreatedDate` column of my  table "websites"

```
create trigger [dbo].[trgrforcreateddate] on [dbo].[Websites] 
after insert
as
update dbo.websites 
set CreatedDate=getdate() from websites w inner join inserted i on w.website=i.website where w.website=i.website
```

It worked, only one should get updated with Created date (actually, the expected row is updated). But as a result I see 
" rows updated"

Why?

Comment: As a result "15  Rows updated" (15th row is the one inserted newly)

Comment: After insert you are updating a date column with getdate(). Why not just use a default getdate() on that column instead of using a trigger?

Comment: What is the PK of the table `Websites`?

Comment: the column "Website" is the PK

Comment: Does it change anything if you change "update dbo.websites " to "update w"?

Comment: Yes, its "lastupdateddate". It was changed to all the rows of data on m y table after one single update one row. this is because I dint use the join on update trigger. Thats very clear. It was expected. But on the trigger created date, I used join with pseudo table inserted just ensure only the row that is inserted just now gets the "CreatedDate" updated. But, it didn't happen

Comment: I have no idea what your last comment means.   If you can post a complete script that reproduces the issue, we might be able to answer the question as to why it happens.  With the little information you have provided, there are too many possible answers.

Answer (score 2):

For this you should be using a default constraint on `CreatedDate` instead of a trigger.

```
alter table dbo.websites add constraint df_websites_CreatedDate default getdate() for CreatedDate;
```

---

The trigger is not joining on a unique id, if it was you would see only 1 row affected for each insert. You should also use `set nocount on;` to prevent extra row result messages from being returned, but in this case it was good that it was not set so that you noticed the error.

```
alter trigger [dbo].[trgrforcreateddate] on [dbo].[Websites] 
after insert
as
begin;
  set nocount on;
  update w
  set w.CreatedDate=getdate() 
  from dbo.websites w
    inner join inserted i
      on w.id = i.id;
end;
```

Comment: Thats ok. I know. But, what is the actual miss here.Can some one help

Comment: I meant  to ask that is the definition for trigger correct?

Comment: The issue is probably that your website column values are not unique. But this answer will fix your problem and the incorrect table design too.

Comment: Could be. I am just practicing.. just learnt the concept of triggers and applied it om table:)